# Include array index when shifting array to delete duplicates C

Tags: arrays, c

I am given an array of randomly generated values, and have to delete duplicates by shifting them down and replacing the duplicate value with a 0 at the end of the array.
Once I find a duplicate index, I start from there and shift my array elements down, however this results in skipping that first index.
I am unsure how to include the 'matched' index as well.

```
int k, i = 0, j;
while (i < size){
    j= i+1;
    while (j < size){
        if (array[i] == array[j]) {
            
            for (k = j; k < size-1; k++) {
                array[k] = array[k+1];
            }
            array[k] = 0;
        }
        ++j;
    }
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: An alternative approach to the algorithm is to perform a `memmove` on te remaining part of the array, and then setting the last element to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Don't increment `j` when you find a match, so you can check it again after shifting.

```
int k, i = 0, j;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    j= i+1;
    while (j < size){
        if (array[i] == array[j]) {
            for (k = j; k < size-1; k++) {
                array[k] = array[k+1];
            }
            array[k] = 0;
        } else {
            ++j;
        }
    }
}
```